# Best Practices: Callout retry

Tags: scheduled-apex, callout

I'm trying to implement an **auto-retry** method on `callout` fail.

I notice that is better ***to wait some prudential time*** to make the retry call, to avoid flooding issues on remote server.

By now, I'm thinking on implement a `schedulable` interface to retry using something like this:

```
try {
    //Execute web service call here     
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);  

} catch(System.CalloutException e) {
    //Exception handling goes here.... retry the call
    //instance an schedulable class
}
```

### Questions:

Is it possible to instance a scheaduble class and schedule that job to N minutes after exception was cath?

What could be the best approach to give retryClass the number of attemps already executed? using SchedulableContext ?

Is there any other workarround ?

Comment: Where is this code sitting? Batch, Controller?

Comment: This code is called on a future method from a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you can insert the failed record Id into a separate custom object and also stamp the time your batch started .Then when your batch finishes you can schedule the job on the custom object to pick the inserted records due to failed transaction and remember to mark a check box or delete from the custom object if the transaction succeeded .

Caution:There are limits on no of scheduled jobs at a time .

Comment: Thanks Mohith, but I don't get how can I schedule the job N minutes after `Now()` ?

Comment: DateTime dtnow = system.now();
String schTime = '0 ' + (dtnow.minute()+1) + ' ' + dtnow.hour() + ' ' + dtnow.day() + ' ' + dtnow.month() + ' ? ' + dtnow.year();
System.schedule('Scheduled Job Name', schTime, new YOURSCHEDULABLECLASSNAME());

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I was dealing with the same issue. It turned out to be nasty little issue and since I could not find a satisfactory solution I have build a [little generic framework](https://github.com/jantaks/salesforce-apex-retry) which I put on Github. I hope this will help others.