# How to retry the callout on http request timed out in rest apex callouts?

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, rest, apexrest

Below is the code. Can anyone tell how to implement retry logic when the 2 minutes http request get timed out.

```
public static void sendOptyInfo(Set <Id> oppIdSet) {
    try{
        for (Opportunity opp: [SELECT id ,StageName, Account.Name  from Opportunity where id in: oppIdSet]){
            
            String jsonBody = JSON.serialize(new Wrapper(opp));
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
            
            Http http = new Http();
            
            Api_Request__c apiReq = new Api_Request__c();
            apiReq.Opportunity__c = opp.id;
            apiReq.Stage_Name__c = opp.StageName;
            apiReq.Account_Name__c = opp.Account.Name;
            
            insert apiReq;
            
            request.setEndpoint('');
            request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json'); 
            request.setMethod('GET');
            request.setBody(jsonBody);
            request.setTimeout(120000);
            system.debug('opp json' +jsonBody);
            
            response = http.send(request);
            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                System.debug('Response-' + response);
                Object results = (Object) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    catch(System.CalloutException e){
        System.debug('Error-' + e.getMessage());   
    }
}
```

Comment: In short, you should be looking at a custom framework to carry out such attempt. Storing the failed record IDs on a custom table to be later retried by a schedulable job would be my preference. You can built error reporting into this also to find out common HTTP failures to debug further. This old [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15148/best-practices-callout-retry) might help you out too.

Comment: Can I get some example or sample code ?

Comment: There are a number of answered Q&As on this topic, I linked another one. Please do a search.